Tkinter OOP for one window with multiple subframes
I wrote a GUI in Tkinter with a lot of widgets. The GUI works but it's quite confusing based on this many variables. So I thought and researched if it's maybe easier to put the subframes in subclasses.
In principle my Gui is structured like this:

A similar question is asked here (Link) but the responses go more into the direction of structuring the GUI more into the widgets instead of the sections. That's why I'm not so sure if I'm on the right path. I tested it with the following code but have already has mysterious problems:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class main_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Adding a title to the window
        #self.wm_title("LiL-SimReg")
        self.geometry("800x1000")
        self.title(" xxx ")
        
        INPUTframe(self)
        
class INPUTframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Frame(self, width=800, height=150).place(x=0,y=0)

        
        label10 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',12)).place(x=10,y=0)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10)).place(x=30, y=30)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text='xxx').place(x=100,y=30)#,command = lambda: path(1))
        textentry1=tk.StringVar()
        entry1 = tk.Entry (self, textvariable=textentry1).place(x=160,y=30,width="350")
        label11 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10)).place(x=500,y=30)


        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10)).place(x=30,y=60)
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text='xxx').place(x=100,y=60)#,command = lambda: path(2))
        textentry2=tk.StringVar()
        entry2 = tk.Entry (self, textvariable=textentry2).place(x=160,y=63,width="350")
        label21 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10)).place(x=500,y=60)
        textentry21=tk.DoubleVar(value='x')
        entry21 = tk.Entry (self, textvariable=textentry21).place(x=580,y=63,width="30")

        label3 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10)).place(x=30,y=90)
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text='xxx').place(x=100,y=90)#,command = lambda: path(3))
        textentry3=tk.StringVar()
        entry3 = tk.Entry (self, textvariable=textentry3).place(x=160,y=93,width="350")
        label31 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10)).place(x=500,y=90)
        textentry31=tk.DoubleVar(value='x')
        entry31 = tk.Entry (self, textvariable=textentry31).place(x=580,y=93,width="30")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testObj = main_window()
    testObj.mainloop()

If I use .place for the widgets it works sometimes. Better it works with .pack but also not always so it seems my approach is wrong. There is no error it just doesn't or only randomly depicts the widgets.
Could you give me input if the approach makes sense and what is the mistake in my code?

Why do you have tk.Frame(...).place(x=0,y=0)? It creates a frame and places it without ever putting any widgets inside. Also look at the Grid geometry manager which might be more useful given your diagram

Hi @TheLizzard, with that command I want to position the INPUTFRAME

Use self.place(...).

@acw1668 I alredy tried, self.place() but it doesnt work as expected. WHere do I need to put it exactly?

@Bryan Oakley I find your name in a lot of questions regarding this. Do you know why it doesnt work with place so well?

Add text to your Gui structure image, it's not clear where each label/entry/button should be placed. I don't know what it should look like.

Use self.place(...) to replace the line tk.Frame(...).place(...).

To position the INPUTframe, you need to update its __init__.
class INPUTframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=800, height=150):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=width, height=height)
        self.place(x=0, y=0)

        label10 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',12)).place(x=10,y=0)
...


You can also structure your application as in this example (one class).

Does this what the GUI look like?
I am using Python 3.12.5. If you do not, then ignore your parent.
I changed (self,...)
to (parent, ...)  for every widgets
On line 20, label10 = tk.Label(parent, text="xxx", bg='red', font=('Arial',12)).place(x=30,y=10) #<== change layout.
Screenshot:


thank you very much. That works! Do you know why .place() didnt worked? Is it the function or was it the inheriting error I made? With .grid() and .place() I was able to bring it to work with the disadvantage that I would need to change the whole layout since so far I mainly worked with .place()

Your place() layout does your job. There are so many ways to do it.

If you want to layout the frame inside __init__() function, you should not call:
tk.Frame(self, width=800, height=150).place(x=0,y=0)

because it will create another frame instead.
Use self.place(x=0, y=0, width=800, height=150) instead.
However I would suggest not calling layout function by widget itself.  It is the responsibility of the parent to layout its children instead:
...

class main_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Adding a title to the window
        #self.wm_title("LiL-SimReg")
        self.geometry("800x1000")
        self.title(" xxx ")
        
        frame = INPUTframe(self, width=800, height=150)
        frame.place(x=0, y=0)

class INPUTframe(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, **kwargs)

        label10 = tk.Label(self, text="xxx", font=('Arial',12)).place(x=10,y=0)
        ...


First of all, when you declare a widget as a variable, you can't add pack /place along with it. instead,
widget = Widget_type(parent_widget)
widget.pack() # or place

Also the function which is triggered by a widget should be mentioned in the following way.
btn = Button(parent_widget, command = function_name) # or lambda function instead of function_name
btn.pack() # or place

Your required behavior can easily be achieved using pack. I assumed label1 & button1 on left side and entry1 and label11 on right side. This combined widget comes as 2nd from the top. (As I understood from your drawing). I was not into where you had placed using the place method.
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class main_window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        # Adding a title to the window
        #self.wm_title("LiL-SimReg")
        self.geometry("800x1000")
        self.title(" xxx ")
        
        


        top_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        top_frame.pack(side = 'top')
        label10 = tk.Label(top_frame, text="xxx", font=('Arial',12))
        label10.pack(side = 'top')
        
        second_top = tk.Frame(self)
        second_top.pack(side = 'top', pady=20)
        
        second_top_left = tk.Frame(second_top)
        second_top_left.pack(side= 'left')
        second_top_right = tk.Frame(second_top)
        second_top_right.pack(side= 'right')
        
        # assuming label1 & button1 on left side and entry1 and label11 on right side 
        label1 = tk.Label(second_top_left, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10))
        label1.pack(side= 'top')
        button1 = tk.Button(second_top_left, text='xxx')
        button1.pack(side = 'top')
        textentry1=tk.StringVar()
        entry1 = tk.Entry (second_top_right, textvariable=textentry1)
        entry1.pack(side='top')
        label11 = tk.Label(second_top_right,  text="xxx", font=('Arial',10))
        label11.pack(side='top')

        third_top = tk.Frame(self)
        third_top.pack(side='top', pady = 20)
        label2 = tk.Label(third_top, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10))
        label2.pack(side = 'top')
        button2 = tk.Button(third_top, text='xxx')
        button2.pack(side = 'top')
        textentry2=tk.StringVar()
        entry2 = tk.Entry (third_top, textvariable=textentry2)
        entry2.pack(side = 'top')
        label21 = tk.Label(third_top, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10))
        label21.pack(side = 'top')
        textentry21=tk.DoubleVar(value='x')
        entry21 = tk.Entry (third_top, textvariable=textentry21)
        entry21.pack(side = 'top')
        
        bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        bottom_frame.pack(side= 'top', pady = 20)

        label3 = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10))
        label3.pack(side = 'top')
        button3 = tk.Button(bottom_frame, text='xxx')
        button3.pack(side = 'top')
        textentry3=tk.StringVar()
        entry3 = tk.Entry (bottom_frame, textvariable=textentry3)
        entry3.pack(side = 'top')
        label31 = tk.Label(bottom_frame, text="xxx", font=('Arial',10))
        label31.pack(side = 'top')
        textentry31=tk.DoubleVar(value='x')
        entry31 = tk.Entry (bottom_frame, textvariable=textentry31)
        entry31.pack(side = 'top')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testObj = main_window()
    testObj.mainloop()


